# how to trun a Future<void>main to a Future<List> in dart flutter without errors

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, dart-webui

I would like please to turn the code below to be :

```
Future<List> fetchPrices() async {details in code below}
```

without having errors.

The code to be changed is here:

```
Future<void> main(List<String> arguments) async {
  Map<String, num> quotes = await Forex.fx(
    quoteProvider: QuoteProvider.yahoo,
    base: 'USD',
    quotes: <String>['EUR', 'JPY']
  );
  print('Number of quotes retrieved: ${quotes.keys.length}.');
  print('Exchange rate USDEUR: ${quotes['USDEUR']}.');
  print('Exchange rate USDJPY: ${quotes['USDJPY']}.');
  quotes = await Forex.fx(
    quoteProvider: QuoteProvider.ecb,
    base: 'JPY',
    quotes: <String>['EUR', 'USD']
  );
  print('Number of quotes retrieved: ${quotes.keys.length}.');
  print('Exchange rate JPYEUR: ${quotes['JPYEUR']}.');
  print('Exchange rate JPYUSD: ${quotes['JPYUSD']}.');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code example `Forex.fx()` return `Map<String, num>`. So you have two options here.

```
Future<List<String>> fooFunction(List<String> arguments) async {
  Map<String, num> quotes = await Forex.fx(
      quoteProvider: QuoteProvider.yahoo,
      base: 'USD',
      quotes: <String>['EUR', 'JPY']
  );
  return quotes.keys;
}

Future<List<num>> fooFunction(List<String> arguments) async {
  Map<String, num> quotes = await Forex.fx(
      quoteProvider: QuoteProvider.yahoo,
      base: 'USD',
      quotes: <String>['EUR', 'JPY']
  );
  return quotes.values;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, i tried that and here is the error shown: lib/main.dart:32:30: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
          future: fetchPrices(),
                             ^
lib/wp-api.dart:18:19: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Future<List<num>> fetchPrices(List<String> arguments) async {

Comment: appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Financial Markets Prices'),),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchPrices(), //error on parenthesis 
          builder: (context,snapshot){
            if(snapshot.hasData) {
             return ListView.builder(
               itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
               itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                 Map quotes = snapshot.data[index];
                 return Column(
                   children: <Widget>[
                 Text('Exchange rate USDEUR: ${quotes['USDJPY']}.'),

Comment: You are returning List<num> from  `fetchPrices` method. But inside `itemBuilder` you want it to return List<Map>,  `Map quotes = snapshot.data[index];` , I didn't get your intention.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have `return` statement.
Edit
Example:

```
Future<List> fooFunction() async {
    Map<Bar, Baz> data = await someAsyncFunction();
    List<String> strings = List();
    strings.add(data.value);
    [...]
    return strings;
}
```

Comment: exactly this is the issue, can you please tell with the code below what can i put in return?

Comment: You have to define what do you want to achieve. Do you want to return raw data from `Forex.fx(...)`  call or do you want to process it and then return it?

Comment: when i put only this code, i retreive data in console, but what i am trying to do is to have these data in my home page screen

Comment: You have this in your console cause you print it with print statement but if you want to return them you have to create list, add elements to it and then return it.

Comment: return ListView.builder(
               itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
               itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                 Map quotes = snapshot.data[index];
                 return Text('Exchange rate USDEUR: ${quotes['USDEUR']}.');
               },

Comment: above is a part of my code, but the screen is loading without showing data!